# azure (ARM) VM status stuck on "updating" - after a dns change at NIC via portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

My VM's is stuck on "updating" for a hours since yesterday. I am not sure if this is normal? The VM's were working perfectly before, but then i had to update the DNS server on the NIC ( for name resolution).I tried reboot of the servers but each time it up, it goes to UPDATING status. I tried to see any logs, but there is none, i mean no errors. Also boot image does not loads, when trying to see that VM screen. I am using new portal. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it actually working though? The Portal does occasionally get stuck on certain messages even though the underlying process has finished.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I have had several ARM deployments get stuck in this state (though the VMs themselves continue to function!)